# AWS Mobile Hub - How to get the User name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I have created a sample Android app using AWS mobile hub. Followed the Developer guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)  and Added User Sign-in to Mobile App with Amazon Cognito.

Created a user and am successful in logging in. After logging in, I want to find the username with which i have logged in. These details will be sent to database to have a record on how many users have logged in.

Can any one suggest me how to fetch the username

Comment: Hi, you could use `getUserPool()` method's `getCurrentUser()` and then call `getDetails()` which has the username and all other information. You can also explicitly store the username information if its not available, and then also store in database of your choice.

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for the info. I am unable to find the appropriate instance to call getUserPool() and its subsequent methods. Can you please share more details on how exactly this call should be made? I am not creating any user pool programmatically. I have created user pool using AWS Cognito Mobile Hub console and in app i have logged in with the created credentials. Now from the Android app, i want to fetch the username. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I have used below code to get the username:
`CognitoUserPool userpool = new CognitoUserPool(AuthenticatorActivity.this, new AWSConfiguration(AuthenticatorActivity.this));
String str = userpool.getCurrentUser().getUserId();`

Comment: Format your answer